# <input type="submit" name=""> почему-то не работает как можно отправить свой текст подскажите

Tags: input, submit

```
<form action="mailto:info@londonappbrewery.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <label>Your name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="YourName" value=""><br>
    <label>Your email</label>
    <input type="email" name="YourEmail" value=""><br>
    <label>Your number</label>
    <input type="number" name="YourNumber" value=""><br>
    <label>Your message:</label><br>
    <textarea name="YourMessage" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <label>Upload file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="YourMessage" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Comment: Сформулируйте проблему точнее. Вы хотите отправить письмо на почту средствами html?

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите отправить содержание формы на почту? Через html это не сделаешь. Отправьте форму на сервер, а сервер уже отправит письмо.

Для отправки письма на севере вам, скорее всего, понадобится библиотека, где надо будет указать "кому" и логин и пароль "от кого".